# Extra 1px white line after footer?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

**Hello !**

I'm running a blog, using a theme I customized myself, but I facing a weird issue on some pages of it. Homepage doesn't look affected, neither do regular pages. However, category pages are impacted by the issue.

My blog is here : http://www.salutparis.fr/decouvrir (it's a category page)

Screenshot of the footer (i placed the image over a gray background in photoshop so you can spot it easily) : [image]

It seems actually happening only on category pages, you can reproduce it on different browsers (tried on desktop and mobile Chrome, Edge...).

With my limited CSS knowledge, I just can't pinpoint the issue. There is no extra margin here, no extra border, nothing. Actually hiding the whole footer div with display: none and changing the body's background color to black still shows this extra 1px white line, after the body ! Is this a browser bug ? (probably not)

Any smart idea on this issue ?!

Comment: Deleted my answer.  Sorry for misunderstanding.  I'm unable to reproduce this issue in Chrome 67.0.3396.99 or Firefox 61.0.1 on Linux.

Comment: I actually added a screenshot to make it more clear ! It happens on Safari on iphone too, really puzzled

Comment: cannot find the issue, but if it possible you can use a cheat on html element, give `html {background:black;}`

Comment: That's a work around that works ! Thank ! But what could this extra pixel line be due to ?

Comment: the problem is .screen-reader-text is consuming 1px height at the bottom of your page. if you change the height to 0 it will go away. the hack above works since that div does not set a background color.

Answer (score 0):

after searching for a long time i found your issue, you have a div with a class `screen-reader-text` which is positioned absolute with a height of 1px, that is the reason for your line at the bottom, i am not sure what you use it for, i just tried `display:none;` and it works. Hope you can fix it.

Comment: Thank you for spotting this, can you please share with me how you spotted this precisely so I (and maybe others here) can understand where to look for in case of issues like this ? Did you just check with chrome's 'inspect element' ? Thank you !

Comment: @Okkx, yeah just played with chrome inspector for sometime :)

Comment: Great find, I will check tomorrow that little class and take approriate action, thanks to you and you guys !